# How to use grep multiple pattern and remove the first pattern

Tags: linux, bash, grep, json

The code that I've tried is not getting the exact output that I want.
This is my code that I've tried:

```
   curl -s --request GET \
    http://10.10.5.242/api/v1/incidents \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json;" \
    -H "X-Cachet-Token: ROvbssneyYwR8fwNgOWj" \
     | json_pp | grep -e id -e component_id
```

And it will output this

```
 "component_id" : "4",
 "id" : 1,
 "id" : 2,
 "component_id" : "4",
 "id" : 3,
 "component_id" : "4",
 "component_id" : "4",
 "id" : 4
 "component_id" : "3",
 "id" : 5,
 "component_id" : "2",
 "id" : 6,
```

This is the content of the api the I'm using http://10.10.5.242/api/v1/incidents

```
{
        "meta": {
            "pagination": {
                "total": 6,
                "count": 6,
                "per_page": 20,
                "current_page": 1,
                "total_pages": 1,
                "links": {
                    "next_page": null,
                    "previous_page": null
                }
            }
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "component_id": "4",
                "name": "Service Unavailable",
                "status": "4",
                "visible": 1,
                "message": "Server is not responding",
                "scheduled_at": "2018-02-26 10:05:03",
                "created_at": "2018-02-23 14:56:16",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-26 08:37:11",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "human_status": "Fixed"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "component_id": "4",
                "name": "Service Unavailable",
                "status": "4",
                "visible": 1,
                "message": "Server is not responding",
                "scheduled_at": "2018-02-26 10:05:03",
                "created_at": "2018-02-23 15:39:52",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-26 08:37:11",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "human_status": "Fixed"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "component_id": "4",
                "name": "Service Unavailable",
                "status": "4",
                "visible": 1,
                "message": "Server is not responding",
                "scheduled_at": "2018-02-26 10:05:03",
                "created_at": "2018-02-26 08:15:43",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-26 08:37:12",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "human_status": "Fixed"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "component_id": "4",
                "name": "Service Unavailable",
                "status": "4",
                "visible": 1,
                "message": "Server is not responding",
                "scheduled_at": "2018-02-26 10:05:03",
                "created_at": "2018-02-26 08:19:12",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-26 08:37:12",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "human_status": "Fixed"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "component_id": "3",
                "name": "Service Unavailable",
                "status": "2",
                "visible": 1,
                "message": "Server is not responding",
                "scheduled_at": "2018-02-26 10:05:03",
                "created_at": "2018-02-26 10:01:32",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-26 10:01:32",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "human_status": "Identified"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "component_id": "2",
                "name": "Service Unavailable",
                "status": "2",
                "visible": 1,
                "message": "Server is not responding",
                "scheduled_at": "2018-02-26 10:05:03",
                "created_at": "2018-02-26 10:03:38",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-26 10:03:38",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "human_status": "Identified"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The output that I want is to get all the **id** of  **"component_id": "4"**, and will output this

```
"id" : 1,
"id" : 2,
"id" : 3,
"id" : 4,
```

What I've wanted is grep the component_id and will get the all of the values of id of component id. 
Cause my plan is to bring those values in my for loop.

Comment: ahh... please don't cross post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980643/how-to-use-grep-multiple-pattern-and-remove-the-first-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
curl -s --request GET \
    http://10.10.5.242/api/v1/incidents \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json;" \
    -H "X-Cachet-Token: ROvbssneyYwR8fwNgOWj" |
jq '.data[] | select(.component_id=="4").id'
```

Assuming that the data is delivered in the JSON form that you quote in the question, this will generate

```
1
2
3
4
```

These are the `id` of the objects in the `data` part of the JSON that has `component_id` equal to 4.

To get the *exact* output that you requested, use

```
jq -r '.data[] | select(.component_id=="4") | "\"id\": \(.id),"'
```

For the given document, this generates

```
"id": 1,
"id": 2,
"id": 3,
"id": 4,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
grep -B1 "\"component_id\": \"4\"" | grep  "\"id\":" | sed 's/^ *//g'
```

- `B1`: get the line before the match too
- `sed 's/^ *//g'`: remove leading and trailing spaces

Esample:

```
echo sample | grep -B1 "\"component_id\": \"4\"" | grep  "\"id\":" | sed 's/^ *//g'
```

The result will be:

```
"id": 1,
"id": 2,
"id": 3,
"id": 4,
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, But I've already figured how can I fixed it.
and this is my code.
` curl -s --request GET \
http://10.10.5.242/api/v1/incidents \
-H "Content-Type: application/json;" \
-H "X-Cachet-Token: ROvbssneyYwR8fwNgOWj" \
 | jsonpp | grep -B1 '"component_id": "4",' | grep -v '"component_id": "4",' |  grep -o '[0-9]\+' `